# "USB host" debugging with Android x86

Tags: java, android, x86, usb, android-x86

I'm trying to develop an application which acts as a Android USB Host however I need to know whether the Android x86 running in VirtualBox or Vmware player can be used for this purpose.

**UPDATE:**

If using live-android works do I have to:

- Install a sepate USB Host driver

To be able to run this simple USB Host app:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
...  
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
```

Comment: It works with Android x86 in VirtualBox for sure. I have never used Vmware player with it before

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes I tried running in Vmware player but I am not getting any response

Comment: @knowbody Did you use live-android? or something else?

Comment: @xybrek yes, live-android

Comment: @knowbody did you have to install a separate android USB host driver or it works out of the box? I mean, if I make a simple USB Host app based on the Android developer's website it should work. Which specific live-android version did you use?

Comment: out of the box, I don't remember installing anything extra. liveandroid0.3

Comment: @knowbody Looks like live-android is running Android less than version 3.1 so I guess UsbManager will not work.